# Offsite data storage for simple app, or a similar supported persistence mechanism?

Tags: facebook

**Question**
Is there a *usable* facebook entry point to the [Data Storage API](https://developers.facebook.com/) that facebook lists on their app admin page for developers, or should I consider an alternate mechanism? What  alternative mechanisms exist to *simply* persist my information offsite (away from my server app) without stuffing it into a cookie that's prone to expire? 
...

**Background**
The facebook Data Store Admin tool is made available in a facebook App's Settings as seen here: (continue reading below)

[image]

However when I visit the [DataStoreAdmin](https://developers.facebook.com/) link nothing works (i.e. clicking the buttons to define the data store types and objects does nothing - I have tried different browsers).

The [Wiki page for Data Store API](https://web.archive.org/web/20090701103007/http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Data_Store_API_documentation) hasn't been updated recently and the second last update says the beta Data Store was taken offline.

It seems odd the link would be readily available and highly visible at the top of the App configuration area if indeed it's defunct. I was hoping some kind of key/value pair solution to remove the data calls from my own server.

Comment: The original downvote for this question does not provide any reason in comments. I guess somebody has something against programming for the facebook platform!?

Comment: Downvotes seem odd. My answer below may not be an answer, just a 'me too' but there be downvotes; someone doesn't like FB it seems!

Comment: I think people expect 'me toos' to be comments rather than answers - otherwise if everybody posted ME Too answers it would be a lot of fodder to scroll through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataStore API is being deprecated, don't use it! You can see this [here](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/deprecations). You are advised to store the data yourself on your server.

Comment: Indeed that's what I'll have to do. All roads I've traveled in search of a facebook data store have resulted in dead ends.